# How can I substitute text between fixed keywords with new text?

Tags: perl

I have an existing Perl script that spits out text like this:

```
set a = 4
set b = 5
set c = 0
set d = 3
```

Now I would like to modify this script to update the contents of a text file. The file looks something like this:

```
...

// BEGIN

set a = 1
set b = 4
set c = 5

// END

...
```

How can I replace the lines between `// BEGIN` and `// END` with the text that was generated by my existing Perl script?

Comment: Can you just put the code that you have done it ? It gives clear picture what exactly you have done ?

Answer (score 1):

`-` is used as second "file" to read from `STDIN`,

```
perl existing.pl | perl -pe'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV=pop; @c =<> }
  $r = /BEGIN/ .. /END/;
  if ($r >1 and $r !~ /E0/) { $_ = ""; print @c if $r ==2 }
' file -
```

output

```
...
...

// BEGIN
set a = 4
set b = 5
set c = 0
set d = 3
// END

..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) or any of the other methods demonstrated in [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'file.txt';

# Your script generated data:
my $newdata = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# Insert new content
local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I   = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    if ( my $range = m{// BEGIN} .. m{// END} ) {
        print if $range == 1;
        print "$newdata$_" if $range =~ /E/;
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
unlink "$file$^I";    # Optionally delete backup

__DATA__
set a = 4
set b = 5
set c = 0
set d = 3
```